# Conditional Formatting Color fill in Adobe Acrobat DC

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

[image]I am trying to conditionally format a field in my PDF to fill with a certain color based on the selected dropdown list's value. It seems i have gotten some traction, but the only color that works is red, and it does not change colors if I select a different value from my dropdown. I need help with my Javascript. Here is what I have so far:

```
var v = this.getField("Dropdown4.4").value;
if (v="Business Now") {event.target.fillColor = color.green;}
if (v="Business Future") {event.target.fillColor = color.blue;}
if (v="Daily To-Do's") {event.target.fillColor = color.red;}                    
if (v="Marketing") {event.target.fillColor = color.orange;}
if (v="Learning Plan") {event.target.fillColor = color.yellow;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the same script into a custom format script. The format script runs after the value has been committed but before the field loses focus. In the mouse up event, the value hasn't actually changed yet.

Comment: I put that script into a custom format, and it still doesn't seem to be working as expected. It automatically fills red and doesn't change once the value changes

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you change

```
var v = this.getField("Dropdown4.4").value ;
```

to

```
var v = event.target.value ;
```

Also, instead of a series of if()… statements, you might also use the switch()… statement.